# Creating ByteString from String representation of chars in Haskell

Tags: haskell, bytestring

I'm trying to create Char8 ByteString from String of already converted to bytes Chars.

For example for String "65" I want ByteString on which unpack method will give me "A". Because 65 is equal to `chr 65`. It would be better if this method will able to work with digits in hex representation. So I want something like this:

```
toByteString :: String -> ByteString
toByteString s = **** s

--Numbers bettwen 0 and 255 or 00 and ff
someBS = toByteString " 72 97 115 107 104 101 108 108" -- evaluates to ByteString

str :: String
str bs = unpack someBS -- evaluates to "Haskhell"
```

I already tried to find something what I want in documentation  for `ByteString.Char8` and `Char`, but it seems that there is no built in methods for my purpose in these libraries. Maybe I'm missing something.

I think there is must be a way to create ByteString from chars and somehow it's not obvious enough to find it

Comment: plenty of results on [Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=String%20-%3E%20ByteString). (You most likely want the first-listed one, `pack`.)

Comment: @RobinZigmond
pack creates bytestring from string. In my case ``unpack $ pack "72 97 115 107 104 101 108 108"`` will result in  "72 97 115 107 104 101 108 108". I want to  ``unpack $ functionIWant "72 97 115 107 104 101 108 108"`` result in "Haskhell"

Comment: oh, so your string is actually a stringified sequence of space-separated ascii numeric values that you want to convert to a (byte)string? That's a rather strange format, but it should be simple enough to do - why don't you show what you've tried?

Comment: Split on spaces with `words`, use `read` on each element to get an `Int`, then convert each to a `Char` with `chr` or `toEnum`. You don't need `ByteString` for this.

Comment: What should happen to `"206 155"`? (In other words, what is your relationship with encodings here?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't start from a `String`, if you can help it. For example, native Haskell syntax already supports numbers in both decimal and hexadecimal:

```
Data.ByteString> pack [72, 97, 115, 107, 104, 101, 108, 108]
"Haskhell"
Data.ByteString> pack [0x48, 0x61, 0x73, 0x6b, 0x68, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c]
"Haskhell"
```

If you must start from `String`, any parser combinator library will work fine for getting you from `" 72 97 115"` to `[72, 97, 115]` -- or even just `map read . words`.

```
> import qualified Data.ByteString as BS
BS> BS.pack . map read . words $ " 72 97 115 107 0x68 0x65 0x6c 0x6c"
"Haskhell"
```